# passing a list argument to llply

Tags: r, plyr, lapply

I've never found a satisfactory answer to this question. Assuming I have a function:

```
foo <- function(a,b,c) {
...
}
```

`a` is a list containing many `data.frame` objects

`b` is a list containing a special class of data (class `ppp` from library `spatstat` if that helps any).

`c` is an integer.

and I want to push a list through that function:

```
result <- llply(a, foo, b,c)
```

The names of list items in `b` correspond to the column "type" in the data.frames in list `a`. So inside function `foo` I can quickly do:

```
id <- which(names(b) == unique(a$type))
baseline_pattern <- b[[id]]
```

to match each underlying spatial pattern in b with the right data.frame in a. There are about 10 items in b and 1000s of items in a. Unfortunately this doesn't work because `llply` (or `lapply` in general) tries to push one list item at `a` time, even for argument list `b` and the two lines of code matching the correct list item in `b` with the correct data frame fails because the function no longer has the entire list `b`. Is there any way around this?

In a pinch, I could create another list (effectively combining `a` and `b`) where each list item is itself a list with length 2 containing the `data.frame` and the corresponding point pattern object. But this will result in 1000s of redundant copies (and make running this operation on a cluster far less efficient).

**UPDATE**: I plan to turn this into a `mclapply` to run this on a cluster. I cannot do that with `mapply` (unless there is a `mcmapply`).

Comment: As it turns out there is a `mcmapply` in R 2.15.0. Time to upgrade...?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't woken up completely yet, but it sounds like you want to use `mapply` with `MoreArgs=list(b, c)`.